# Adding controls to a frame in an Excel userform with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I need to create labels and buttons dynamically and then add them to a frame within a userform.  How do I do this? Seems like it *should* be easier than it really is.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following code demonstrates how you can dynamically populate a frame in a userform with controls...

In the form I used I had a frame control named Frame1, so in the UserForm_Initialize you call Frame1.Controls.Add to embed a control in the frame.  You can set the control which gets returned to a WithEvents control variable that you have defined in the UserForm code module so you can respond to events on whatever controls you want...

So with this method you need to pre-write any event code you want for any controls you create...

Also note that you can position and size your controls even if the top, left, width, and height properties don't necessarily come up in intellisense...

```
Private WithEvents Cmd As MSForms.CommandButton
Private WithEvents Lbl As MSForms.Label

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set Lbl = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl1")
    Lbl.Caption = "Foo"
    Set Cmd = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "cmd1")
End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_Click()
    Cmd.Top = Cmd.Top + 5
End Sub

Private Sub Lbl_Click()
    Lbl.Top = Lbl.Top + 5
End Sub
```

Comment: Why the `"1"` at the end of the class name in the `add` method?

Comment: I don't know. I know that it doesn't work without that.

Comment: I would really like to know why it has to be  "Forms.CommandButton.1" too

Comment: That "1" is the version.

Answer (score 4):

My variation on the theme above. This is just for a 4x4 array of buttons though. Create a userform and add this to its code. The same concepts can be used with your labels (or see the previous answer):

```
Private cmdLots(20) As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
For i = 1 To 4
For j = 1 To 4
    k = i + (4 * j)
    Set cmdLots(k) = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "cmd1")
    With cmdLots(k)
        .Top = i * 25
        .Left = (j * 80) - 50
        .BackColor = RGB(50 * i, 50 * j, 0)
        .Caption = "i= " & i & "  j= " & j
    End With
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: how to use those sixteen buttons ?

Comment: Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130300/how-do-we-know-the-sender-of-the-buttons-in-vba

Answer (score 4):

### The `Add` Method

To add controls to a userform or a frame you use the [`add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/add-method-microsoft-forms) method.

`SetControl = object.Add(ProgID [, Name [, Visible ]] )`

The first argument is going to reference what type of control you want to add, and it is `ProgID` which is defined as

> Programmatic identifier. A text string with no spaces that identifies an object class. The standard syntax for a ProgID is ... A ProgID is mapped to a class identifier (CLSID).

### A Functional Solution

To make this process easier, let's use an enum to help manage the various controls for us.

```vb
' List of all the MSForms Controls.
Public Enum MSFormControls
    CheckBox
    ComboBox
    CommandButton
    Frame
    Image
    Label
    ListBox
    MultiPage
    OptionButton
    ScrollBar
    SpinButton
    TabStrip
    TextBox
    ToggleButton
End Enum
```

With this enum, we can now easily create a function to get the ProgID string for all controls.

```vb
' Gets the ProgID for each individual control. Used to create controls using `Object.add` method.
' @see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/add-method-microsoft-forms
Public Function GetMSFormsProgID(control As MSFormControls) As String
    Select Case control
      Case MSFormControls.CheckBox:       GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.CheckBox.1"
      Case MSFormControls.ComboBox:       GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.ComboBox.1"
      Case MSFormControls.CommandButton:  GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.CommandButton.1"
      Case MSFormControls.Frame:          GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.Frame.1"
      Case MSFormControls.Image:          GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.Image.1"
      Case MSFormControls.Label:          GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.Label.1"
      Case MSFormControls.ListBox:        GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.ListBox.1"
      Case MSFormControls.MultiPage:      GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.MultiPage.1"
      Case MSFormControls.OptionButton:   GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.OptionButton.1"
      Case MSFormControls.ScrollBar:      GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.ScrollBar.1"
      Case MSFormControls.SpinButton:     GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.SpinButton.1"
      Case MSFormControls.TabStrip:       GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.TabStrip.1"
      Case MSFormControls.TextBox:        GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.TextBox.1"
      Case MSFormControls.ToggleButton:   GetMSFormsProgID = "Forms.ToggleButton.1"
    End Select
End Function
```

And lastly, let's create a function that adds to a form or frame using our new function.

```vb
' Easly add control to userform or a frame.
' @returns {MSForms.control} The control that was created
Public Function AddControl(userformOrFrame As Object _
                         , control As MSFormControls _
                         , Optional name As String = vbNullString _
                         , Optional visable As Boolean = True _
                        ) As MSForms.control
    Set AddControl = userformOrFrame.Controls.Add(GetMSFormsProgID(control), name, visable)
End Function
```

The beauty of using enums like this is that we now have a intellisense for all the controls and don't have to memorize them all.

[image: Demo showing intellisense]

### Demo

To demo it, we can add every control to a blank userform by looping the enum.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    demoAddingControlsToUserform
End Sub

Private Sub demoAddingControlsToUserform()
    ' Offset used to prevent controls
    ' overlapping as well as provide
    ' a height for the scrollbars
    Dim offsetHeight As Double
    
    ' Add each control to the userform
    ' and set top to make sure they are not overlapping
    ' (Although this looks odd, you can actually loop enums this way.)
    Dim control As MSFormControls
    For control = CheckBox To ToggleButton
        With AddControl(Me, control)
            .Top = offsetHeight
            offsetHeight = offsetHeight + .Height
        End With
    Next
    
    ' Show scrollbars and adjust the height to show
    ' all the added controls.
    With Me
        .ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
        .ScrollHeight = offsetHeight + 20
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Demo Userform with all controls]

Comment: You mean "visible" ;)