# How do we know the sender of the buttons in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, events

I would like to find out the **sender** of **many buttons**.

Something like that in **C#**:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "Click 1";
b.Location = new Point(20, 20);
b.Size = new Size(100, 20);
// Our Handler
b.Click += new EventHandler(myClick);

// Implementation of next button...

// Add to form
this.Controls.Add(b);
this.Controls.Add(nextButton);
...

// And our event
private void myClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   var mysender = ((Button)sender).Name;
   doAnything(mysender);
}
```

It is possible in VBA *(Visual Basic for Applications)*? I'm using Excel. I tried **Application.Caller**.

Comment: What type of button is it (forms? activex?) and where is it (on a form, on a worksheet?)  What VBA code did you try?  This can be made to work ,but you need to provide more detail about exactly what you want to do...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to wire up the button events.  You can do so in the Worksheet Activate event handler:

```
Dim arrEvents As Collection

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim objButtonEvents As ButtonEvents
Dim shp As Shape

Set arrEvents = New Collection

For Each shpCursor In Me.Shapes
    If shpCursor.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
        If TypeOf shpCursor.OLEFormat.Object.Object Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
            Set objButtonEvents = New ButtonEvents
            Set objButtonEvents.cmdButton = shpCursor.OLEFormat.Object.Object
            arrEvents.Add objButtonEvents
        End If
    End If
 Next

End Sub
```

Then make a Class Module named ButtonEvents with this code:

```
Public WithEvents cmdButton As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub cmdButton_Click()
 MsgBox cmdButton.Caption & " was pressed!"
End Sub
```

Comment: I just don't get it how is this wired up actually? The first code snippet 'output' is to collects buttons in a certain collection. The seconds says to me to create a classModule, refer a CommandButton and assign an onClick method to it. But how will the actually button reference show up in the classModule?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your Shapes.Name values to something you can use however you need.

When you create a group of shapes in Excel, lets say rectangles, right click the first object then go to the Formulas tab and click "Define Name". At the bottom of the pup-up window will be a line: Refers to [ ="Rectangle 73" ] This is your VBA Shapes.Name value. (Doing anything here will not change the VBA Shapes.Name value)

You can use the individual object name with `IF Application.Caller.Name = "Rectangle 73"` or you can rename your shaped in VBA to something more useful.

If you manually created each shape, they will be "Rectangle 73", "Rectangle 74", "Rectangle 75"... If you copied and pasted, they will be "Rectangle 73", "Rectangle 102", "Rectangle 103"... Now that we have our Shapes.Name values we can redefine them as needed in VBA.

```
Sub nameShapes()
    Dim shp As String
    Dim shpType As String
    Dim myName As String

'original root name of group shapes *do not include trailing space*
    shpType = "Rectangle"

'new name of group shapes
    myName = "newName"

'first number value of new shape names
    n = 1

'number values of first, second, and last shapes
    n1 = 73
    n2 = 103
    nx = 124

'active code --------------------------------------
'--------------------------------------------------
    shp = shpType & " " & n1
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(shp).Name = myName & " " & n

    For x = n2 To nx
        n = n + 1
        shp = shpType & " " & x
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(shp).Name = myName & " " & n
    Next n
'--------------------------------------------------
'active code --------------------------------------
End Sub
```

Place this code in its own separate module, then simply enter the values and click the play button in the VBA window toolbar for RunSub.

Now, you can use `n = Right(Application.Caller, 2)` to get the number value of the button clicked. Be sure to define `Dim n As Integer`.

If different button groups call the same function, you can use `Select Case Left(Application.Caller, 7)` to get the first 7 letters of the shape.name and `Case "newName"` for actions specific to that button group.