# Common event handler to get the name of ActiveX button clicked in VBA.

Tags: excel, vba

So I was wondering if I can reference the button that was clicked. So I do not have to change the code to much for every button. So here is what I have.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim name As String
With CommandButton1

If .Caption = "CommandButton1" & "" Then
name = InputBox("Enter Template Name.")
.Caption = name

End If
End With

End Sub
```

Instead of `With CommandButton1` I want it to use the button that was clicked. I tried `With Me` but it did nothing.

Comment: If you want a common event handle of sorts, I think classes are better suited for getting the name of a clicked button. A single button's name can be determined by using `Application.Caller`. However, I just tested now and it's throwing an error if it's an `ActiveX` button. However, it's fine if it's a `Form` button.

Comment: I am using an active x button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The answer in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130300/how-do-we-know-the-sender-of-the-buttons-in-vba) solves your issue.

Follow the instructions carefully. It should solve your problem. :)

**EDIT:**

It's pretty easy, actually.

**SCREENSHOTS:**

**Set-up of my sheet:**

[image]

**Set-up of the VBE, Sheet1's code:**

[image]

***NOTE THE HIGHLIGHTED PARTS!***

**Set-up of the VBE, Class Module:**

Add a class module by inserting `Class Module` rather than just `Module`. The name should exactly be `ButtonEvents`.

[image]

**Result when CommandButton1 is clicked:**

[image]

**===============**

This is just the basic premise, of course. Instead of showing a message box, you can instead change the code in the class module to have the name stored somewhere or send it to a particular cell, etc.

Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: LOL okay ill take a look

Comment: Thank you for the help I got it from here.