# the commant Me.ActiveControl.Name is giving an error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the name of the button (ActiveX command button) I clicked on my excel workbook but I am getting an error while trying to do that

Button name in the sheet is "Try"
The error I am getting is "Method of Data member not found"

The code I am trying to use is

```
Private Sub Try_Click()
    Dim ButtonName As String
    ButtonName = Me.ActiveControl.Name
    MsgBox ButtonName
```

I want to use the name of the button as a condition to use in creating a filter for a table on a different worksheet (same workbook)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we know the sender of the buttons in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130300/how-do-we-know-the-sender-of-the-buttons-in-vba)

Comment: Or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010716/common-event-handler-to-get-the-name-of-activex-button-clicked-in-vba).

Comment: This would be easier if you don't use ActiveX buttons - you can use (eg) shapes formatted like buttons, set them all to the same "onaction" handler, and use `Application.Caller` inside the called code