# Can you reference the control name within a sub in vba?

Tags: vba

So I'm attempting to filter a large section of data in a spreadsheet with checkboxes. So far around 80 individual checkboxes. I'm wondering if there is anyway to refer to the checkbox (or any other control) name within the sub, as a specific reference, i.e. thiscontrol.name. At present the first checkbox reads:

```
Private Sub_F1_Click()

    StringVariableForLaterUse ="F1"
    If F1.Value = True Then
    'Display Data Relevant to F1
    End If
End
```

I'm wondering if I can use

```
StringVariableForLaterUse = ThisControl.Name
```

and

```
If ThisControl.Value = True Then
```

I'd then be able to replicate this a further 78 times. Currently pure laziness factor, however I want my Subs to be self sufficient as possible. Any thoughts folks?

Comment: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010716/common-event-handler-to-get-the-name-of-activex-button-clicked-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You can never use a string like an object... But, for an ActiveXcheck box, use the next workaround code.

```
 Public chk1 As Shape

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
 Set chk1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(CheckBox1.Name)
 MsgBox chk1.OLEFormat.Object.Object.value
End Sub
```

You can use now `chk1` in another `Sub` inside the sheet module.

You can also refer to it from a module `Sub`, referencing the sheet, too:

```
Sub testSheetChk()
 Debug.Print Worksheets("Sheet Name").chk1.OLEFormat.Object.Object.value
End Sub
```

But, this will work only after you firstly run (once) the click event, in order to alocate a value to the object variable.