# Looping to get data row by row to the userform rows

Tags: loops, excel, vba

I am using VBS Excel 2010, I am trying to write a loop to transfer cells in 17 rows, 5 columns from a WS to a my userform which also has 17 rows, 5 columns of textboxes.

Each row of textboxes are indexed for the row they are in. eg. `txt.Name1`, `txt.City1`...`txt,County1`.  Then the next row of textboxes is `txt.Name2`, `txt.City2`...`txt,County2`...

How can I loop through each row and transfer it to an awaiting row of textboxes with out writing code for every row?

Comment: The best way I can think to do this is to put your Textbox controls into a control array.  Then you can just grab an array or range of the same dimensions and loop over the rows and columns to assign values.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3422829/4088852) and [this one if you need event handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10131002/4088852).

Answer (score 0):

Cominterm is correct, “you need to put your Textbox controls into a control array”.  Unfortunately, I don’t find his suggested links particularly helpful.

I have not needed to access form controls by number for many years so I was rusty.  I tackled this answer in the way I would have done for myself: isolate the functionality I don’t know and write macros to explore that functionality.  I remembered the Controls collection but not how to access the type of a control so I looked that up.

The details of every control on a form are recorded in the Controls collection just as the details of every worksheet are recorded in the Worksheets collection.  If `txtName1` is the 6th control you can access its properties as `Controls(5)`since controls are numbered from zero.  For example, instead of `txtName1.Text = "xxxxxx"`, you can write `Controls(5) .Text = "xxxxxx"`.

I created a user form and filled it with one or two of every type of control.  I then added three rows in the format you want to give:

[image: Design view of form]

I created a module containing:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test1()

  Load UserForm1
  UserForm1.Show vbModal

End Sub
```

I wrote the following code within the form:

```
Private Type TypeCtrl
  Height As Single
  Left As Single
  Name As String
  Parent As String
  Top As Single
  TypeName As String
  Width As Single
End Type
Dim CtrlDtl() As TypeCtrl
Private Sub cmdExit_Click()

  Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Dim InxCtrl As Long
  Dim NameLenMax As Long
  Dim ParentLenMax As Long
  Dim TypeNameLenMax As Long

  ReDim CtrlDtl(0 To Controls.Count - 1)

  For InxCtrl = 0 To Controls.Count - 1

    CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).Name = Controls(InxCtrl).Name
    CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).Top = Controls(InxCtrl).Top
    CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).Left = Controls(InxCtrl).Left
    CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).Width = Controls(InxCtrl).Width
    CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).Height = Controls(InxCtrl).Height
    CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).Parent = Controls(InxCtrl).Parent.Name
    CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).TypeName = TypeName(Controls(InxCtrl))

    If NameLenMax < Len(CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).Name) Then
      NameLenMax = Len(CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).Name)
    End If

    If ParentLenMax < Len(CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).Parent) Then
      ParentLenMax = Len(CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).Parent)
    End If

    If TypeNameLenMax < Len(CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).TypeName) Then
      TypeNameLenMax = Len(CtrlDtl(InxCtrl).TypeName)
    End If

  Next

    If NameLenMax < Len("Name") Then
      NameLenMax = Len("Name")
    End If

    If ParentLenMax < Len("Parent") Then
      ParentLenMax = Len("Parent")
    End If

  Debug.Print "Inx  Name" & Space(NameLenMax - 2) & _
              "     Top      Left    Height     Width  Parent" & _
              Space(ParentLenMax - 6) & "  Type name"
  For InxCtrl = 0 To UBound(CtrlDtl)
    With CtrlDtl(InxCtrl)
      Debug.Print Right("  " & InxCtrl, 3) & "  " & _
                  Left(.Name & Space(NameLenMax), NameLenMax) & "  " & _
                  Right(Space(8) & Format(.Top, "#,###.00"), 8) & "  " & _
                  Right(Space(8) & Format(.Left, "#,###.00"), 8) & "  " & _
                  Right(Space(8) & Format(.Height, "#,###.00"), 8) & "  " & _
                  Right(Space(8) & Format(.Width, "#,###.00"), 8) & "  " & _
                  Left(.Parent & Space(ParentLenMax), ParentLenMax) & "  " & _
                  .TypeName
    End With
  Next

End Sub
```

The first block of code reads down the Controls collection, extracts the values of selected properties and stores then in an array of type `TypeCtrl` which I have specified to hold the selected properties.  The second block outputs the values from the array to the Immediate Windows to give:

```
Inx  Name                 Top      Left    Height     Width  Parent     Type name
  0  Label1             12.00     24.00     18.00     72.00  UserForm1  Label
  1  Label2             12.00    114.00     18.00     72.00  UserForm1  Label
  2  TextBox1           12.00    210.00     18.00     72.00  UserForm1  TextBox
  3  TextBox2           12.00    294.00     18.00     72.00  UserForm1  TextBox
  4  ComboBox1          12.00    390.00     18.00     72.00  UserForm1  ComboBox
  5  ComboBox2          48.15     24.00     18.00     72.00  UserForm1  ComboBox
  6  ListBox1           42.00    120.00     72.00     72.00  UserForm1  ListBox
  7  CheckBox1          48.00    294.00     18.00    108.00  UserForm1  CheckBox
  8  OptionButton1     138.00     12.00     18.00    108.00  UserForm1  OptionButton
  9  ListBox2           42.00    204.00     72.00     72.00  UserForm1  ListBox
 10  CheckBox2          72.00    294.00     18.00    108.00  UserForm1  CheckBox
 11  OptionButton2     162.00     12.00     18.00    108.00  UserForm1  OptionButton
 12  ToggleButton1     132.00    144.00     40.00     36.00  UserForm1  ToggleButton
 13  ToggleButton2     132.00    192.00     40.00     36.00  UserForm1  ToggleButton
 14  Frame1            120.00    246.00     42.00     66.00  UserForm1  Frame
 15  Frame2            120.00    324.00     54.00     72.00  UserForm1  Frame
 16  Label3             18.00     12.00     18.00     48.00  Frame2     Label
 17  cmdExit           126.00    414.00     24.00     72.00  UserForm1  CommandButton
 18  CommandButton2    162.00    414.00     24.00     72.00  UserForm1  CommandButton
 19  TabStrip1         192.00     18.00     54.00     90.00  UserForm1  TabStrip
 20  TabStrip2         198.00    120.00     48.00     66.00  UserForm1  TabStrip
 21  MultiPage1        198.00    186.00     66.00    102.00  UserForm1  MultiPage
 22  MultiPage2        204.00    306.00     60.00     72.00  UserForm1  MultiPage
 23  ScrollBar1        204.00    390.00     63.80     12.75  UserForm1  ScrollBar
 24  SpinButton1       204.00    462.00     25.50     12.75  UserForm1  SpinButton
 25  Image1            270.00     18.00     72.00     72.00  UserForm1  Image
 26  SpinButton2       204.00    486.00     25.50     12.75  UserForm1  SpinButton
 27  ScrollBar2        204.00    414.00     63.80     12.75  UserForm1  ScrollBar
 28  txtName1          282.00    108.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 29  txtStreet1        282.00    156.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 30  txtTown1          282.00    204.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 31  txtCounty1        282.00    252.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 32  txtPostcode1      282.00    300.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 33  txtName2          306.00    108.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 34  txtStreet2        306.00    156.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 35  txtTown2          306.00    204.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 36  txtCounty2        306.00    252.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 37  txtPostcode2      306.00    300.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 38  txtName3          330.00    108.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 39  txtStreet3        330.00    156.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 40  txtTown3          330.00    204.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 41  txtCounty3        330.00    252.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
 42  txtPostcode3      330.00    300.00     18.00     42.00  UserForm1  TextBox
```

I believe you only need to access the name but coding this refreshed my memory of what is possible.  This is the sort of macro I would have written for myself when I first needed to know about the Control collection and I recommend this approach.  I have carefully selected properties that exist for every type of control.  However, by checking the type, I could have accessed properties that are restricted to particular types.

Having refreshed my memory, I was ready to code a macro that matches your requirement.

You do not name all five of your columns so I made up five names of my own.  I have only defined three rows which was enough to demonstrate the approach.  You can see them at the bottom of the list above.

I create a worksheet “Data” and placed some data within it:

[image: Sample data]

I do not know if your data in fixed or movable but for my demonstration I have made it fixed and have defined its location with constants.  You can replace the values of my constants or replace my constants with variables as necessary.

I discarded the original code for the form and replaced it with:

```
Option Explicit

  Const WshtName     As String = "Data"
  Const RowDataTop   As Long = 3
  Const ColDataLeft  As Long = 2
  Const RowDataBot   As Long = 5
  Const ColDataRight As Long = 6

Dim CtrlForAddressElement(1 To ColDataRight - ColDataLeft + 1, _
                          1 To RowDataBot - RowDataTop + 1) As Long
Private Sub cmdExit_Click()

  Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Dim ColDataCrnt As Long
  Dim ColFormCrnt As Long
  Dim InxCtrl As Long
  Dim RowDataCrnt As Long
  Dim RowFormCrnt As Long

  ReDim CtrlDtl(0 To Controls.Count - 1)

  ' Store index number for each control of the address block
  For InxCtrl = 0 To Controls.Count - 1
    If Left(Controls(InxCtrl).Name, 7) = "txtName" Then
      RowFormCrnt = Val(Mid(Controls(InxCtrl).Name, 8))
      CtrlForAddressElement(1, RowFormCrnt) = InxCtrl
    ElseIf Left(Controls(InxCtrl).Name, 9) = "txtStreet" Then
      RowFormCrnt = Val(Mid(Controls(InxCtrl).Name, 10))
      CtrlForAddressElement(2, RowFormCrnt) = InxCtrl
    ElseIf Left(Controls(InxCtrl).Name, 7) = "txtTown" Then
      RowFormCrnt = Val(Mid(Controls(InxCtrl).Name, 8))
      CtrlForAddressElement(3, RowFormCrnt) = InxCtrl
    ElseIf Left(Controls(InxCtrl).Name, 9) = "txtCounty" Then
      RowFormCrnt = Val(Mid(Controls(InxCtrl).Name, 10))
      CtrlForAddressElement(4, RowFormCrnt) = InxCtrl
    ElseIf Left(Controls(InxCtrl).Name, 11) = "txtPostcode" Then
      RowFormCrnt = Val(Mid(Controls(InxCtrl).Name, 12))
      CtrlForAddressElement(5, RowFormCrnt) = InxCtrl
    End If
  Next

  ' Move data from worksheet to form
  With Worksheets(WshtName)
    For RowDataCrnt = RowDataTop To RowDataBot
      RowFormCrnt = RowDataCrnt - RowDataTop + 1
      For ColDataCrnt = ColDataLeft To ColDataRight
        ColFormCrnt = ColDataCrnt - ColDataLeft + 1
        InxCtrl = CtrlForAddressElement(ColFormCrnt, RowFormCrnt)
        Controls(InxCtrl).Text = .Cells(RowDataCrnt, ColDataCrnt).Value
      Next
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

I have a global array `CtrlForAddressElement` which I size as necessary to handle the range defined by the constants.

The first block of code loads that array with the indices into the Controls collection for the 15 text boxes.

The second block of code uses this array to move data from the worksheet to the form to give:

[image: Form loaded with values from the worksheet]

The second block of code should be readily adaptable to your requirement.