# Pass a button Name as parameter to access worksheet to a function or sub

Tags: excel, vba, wiki

I am trying to create a workbook to work as a Wiki (making a wiki is not an option...)
So far I have created the worksheet for each page and I have a Home page with several buttons to access each worksheet and hide all the rest and in each worksheet there is an exit -> go back to the home page button.

I want to assign the same sub to all of the buttons that take the buttons name (the same as the worksheet) as a parameter and take you to that Worksheet hiding all the other sheets.

Is it possible? So far I have created multiple Sub, one for each button Goto and Exist buttons.

Code Draft (one per button created so about 45):

```
Sub GoToPageName1()

Sheet("PageName1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Worksheets("PageName1").Activate
Sheet("HomePage").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

End Sub

Sub ExitingPageName1()

Sheet("HomePage").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Worksheets("HomePage").Activate
Sheet("PageName1").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

End Sub
```

Comment: YES you can do it.> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130300/how-do-we-know-the-sender-of-the-buttons-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

The comment response to your question refers to buttons on a UserForm. If you are using that then great, follow the code in the link.

Judging by the wording you use in your question, it looks as if you may be adding buttons to the sheet itself. If that is the case, then you'll have to take a different route.

The trick is to give your button names the sheet names you are navigating from and to. In the example below I have named the buttons "Sheet1|Sheet2" etc. where the first name is the sheet you're navigating from and the second name is the sheet you're navigating to.

In your handler, you can access the button name from the `Application.Caller` property. So you'd simply parse that string to grab the data you want. Skeleton code would look like this:

```
Sub NavigationClick()
    Dim buttonName As Variant
    Dim nav() As String
    Dim fromSheet As Worksheet, toSheet As Worksheet
    
    buttonName = Application.Caller
    nav = Split(buttonName, "|")
    If (UBound(nav)) <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set fromSheet = .Worksheets(nav(0))
        Set toSheet = .Worksheets(nav(1))
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Err.Number > 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    With toSheet
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
    End With
    
    fromSheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub
```

Each worksheet button would be assigned to this macro.

Comment: The selected answer in comment i added,  works well for ActiveX buttons adding to the sheet itself.