# How to pass the value (true/false) of checkboxes created run-time on a userform

Tags: dynamic, excel, checkbox, vba

I am trying to create a number of checkboxes on a UserForm after reading all the non-empty rows in an excel sheet. That means these checkboxes have to be created in run-time.  I also want to put a CommandButton on the UserForm.  What I want is that once the user presses this CommandButton, the code should be able to send to a subroutine the information on which checkboxes are checked and what their names are.

Could anyone help me with problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems are you having with it?  Posting your current code (even if it doesn't work) is always going to get you more help. Right now all you have is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to dynamically create checkboxes on a userform (which I'm not even sure is possible) consider using a listbox with a ListStyle of fmListStyleOption and with MultiSelect turned on with fmMultiSelectMulti

Populate the Listbox using the AddItem Method

```
For i = 0 to 9
  Me.lbxDivisions.AddItem
  Me.lbxDivisions.List(i) = "Checkbox " & format(i)
Next i
```

And determine which items are checked via the Selected property:

```
For i = 0 To lbxDivisions.ListCount - 1
  If lbxDivisions.Selected(i) Then
    MsgBox "Item " & Format(i) & " is selected and has value " & lbxDivisions.List(i)
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: You **can** add form controls dynamically )`Me.Controls.Add "Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox1", True`), but it's a PITA and I would avoid it definitely in favor of your proposal. Always better to use a dynamic control like a ListBox, than to try and manage temporary controls in memory.

Comment: Thanks @David, it's good to know the dynamic way is possible!  Maybe that's worth including as a separate answer in case the listbox approach won't work for the op?

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically add form controls (check boxes, listboxes, etc) to userforms.  From within the form's code module,

`Me.Controls.Add "Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox1", True)`

From any other code module, just reference the form by name, instead of `Me`, e.g.,

`MyUserForm.Controls.Add "Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox1", True)`

Personally I would favor using a more dynamic control (like a list box or combobox) unless your task absolutely requires you to use check boxes. With dynamic controls you need to manage their size, location relative to other controls, resize the userform (if necessary), etc., and  although it's kind of possible to add event handling to these controls ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563972/adding-controls-to-a-frame-in-an-excel-userform-with-vba)), that's really limited (e.g., if you expect you need to add 10 check boxes each of which do a different thing, you need to pre-write 10 check box subroutines. If you create 11 check boxes but only 10 pre-written routines, the last check box won't do anything. It would be easier to just create all the check boxes when designing the form, and then programmatically set them to `Visible=True` or `Visible=False` as circumstance requires.

So, I'd favor using a dynamic control like a listbox or combobox, but it **is** possible to add form controls like checkboxes at run-time, if you must.