# Add checkboxes to UserForm based on cell value

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I'm very new to VBA, just 3 days... but i found it very useful and easy to use, but now i'm facing a problem.
I need to make a UserForm with different Checkboxes, but i need them to be added automatically based on the information used in one of the columns of a Sheet.
I believe i can use the For .. Each .. Next but i really don't know how to fill the Checkboxes.
This is the only solution that i have right now, but i can't make differents Checkboxes, only one.

```
For Each rCell In Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
    If rCell.Value <> "" Then
        UserForm1.Controls.Add ("Forms.CheckBox.1")
    End If
Next
```

One more thing that i need to do is fill  the properties of the Checkbox once it is added, so i can work with the values after that.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I'm sure you've gotten your answer before now, but since this came up in a Google search of mine, I thought I'd post another answer. Place the following code in your UserForm:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim curColumn   As Long
Dim LastRow     As Long
Dim i           As Long
Dim chkBox      As MSForms.CheckBox

curColumn = 1 'Set your column index here
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, curColumn).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
    Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & i)
    chkBox.Caption = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, curColumn).Value
    chkBox.Left = 5
    chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)
Next i

End Sub
```

You will need to modify the code to suit your specific needs, but that will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this previous answer for a start as it explains the principals you need, I think.

[Add Controls To A Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563972/adding-controls-to-a-frame-in-an-excel-userform-with-vba)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what i'm looking for. I need to add elements in a dynamic way, so, the names for the Form.CheckBox.1 should be something like Form.CheckBox.[i]. That's the first thing at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & i).Value
```