# VBA Looping through checkboxes and getting its name from excel table

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Image1]

[image]

As you can see above, I have a table in a Excel sheet where indication A can have product 1, product 2 and so forth (The prods names are all different depending on the indication, this is just for simplicity!).

In my userform a similar format is presented. I want to basically match the indication name on my excel sheet with the indication name in my userform. If they match, then Product 11 gets A's Prod 1 name, Product 12 gets A's Prod 2 name and so forth.

I've tried the following, but I'm just starting using VBA so I'm sure it probably doesn't even make sense.

```
Dim code_ind As String
Dim sel_ind As String
Dim chkbx As Control
Dim labx As Control
Dim i As Integer
Dim col_value As Integer
Dim row_value As Integer

For i = 1 To 8
For j = 1 To 4
For row_value = 4 To 11
col_value = 0

Set chkbx = Me.Controls("seg_l_selInd_" & i)
Set labx = Me.Controls("seg_cb_selInd_" & i & j)

sel_ind = tWb.Worksheets("LALALA").Columns(2).Find(what:=chkbx)

If code_ind = sel_ind Then
    labx.Name = tWb.Worksheets("LALALA").Cells(row_value, 3 + col_value)
    col_value = col_value + 1
End If
Next row_value
Next j
Next i
```

Is there any way I can do this? I know I could just write the names manually, but I need my tool to be as flexible as possible. Ideally, if more information is added into the excel table, the userform will automatically update.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What is the value of `tWb`, `code_ind`, `chkbx` etc?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want accomplishing... What do you finally want doing with this matching? Do you want changing their caption as the product names, according to their position in the table versus controls matrix? And after that how do you intend to use them? You know, I suppose, that this matching cannot be saved. It is valid only for the form working life. If, you check, let us say the check box having the caption "Product22" would you like selecting "Prod 2" of the second line?

Comment: @FaneDuru as a first step you're right. I want to change their captions as the prod names according to their position in the table versus controls matrix. Please see my solution below and tell me what you think. Secondly, whatever values/checkboxes are ticked will need to be saved in a worksheet, ideally, with the following format: Indication - Product. Hope it makes more sense now. Thank you!

Comment: You did not say anything about what "seg_l_selInd_" means. I understood that the matching will be done according to the controls Caption. First digit after "_" character meaning the row where the product exist, and the second one the column. But even forgetting about this aspect,  I asked what do you want accomplishing. How would you use each control (new) caption in order to make it referring a specific product? I suppose that the  possibility to exist the same product name in a different position. Is this supposition correct. Even if not, how do you intend to use the matching in discussion?

Comment: For instance, the matching in discussion to be done during the Form Initialization event, but during the matching process a Dictionary (Private variable of the form module level) having the key obtained by concatenation between the control Left property and control Top property and value the cell address where the corresponding product exists. When changing its value the real matching should be done based on the Dictionary keys/values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the next way. I tried thinking your project in this way:

1. The form in the next example must be named `frmChkBox`. The check boxes on the form will have names like "CheckBox11", "CheckBox12" and so on, first digit after "CheckBox" string being the row and the next one the column. If you appreciate that your real situation will exceed one digit number for the row number, they can be separated by "_", or something else. You can also create the check boxes on the flay.

a. Please paste in the form code module the next code lines:

```
Option Explicit

Private ChkBColl As New Collection
Private ChkB() As New ChkBoxChClss

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, iRow As Long, iCol As Long
   Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control, ext As String, arrUsed, k As Long
   
   ReDim ChkB(32)
   ReDim arrUsed(Me.Controls.count)
   Set ws = Sheets("INDICATION-PRODUCT")
   Set rng = ws.Range("B2:E9")
   For iRow = 1 To 8
        For iCol = 1 To 4
            For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
                If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
                    If IsError(Application.Match(ctrl.Caption, arrUsed, 0)) Then
                        ext = Right(ctrl.Caption, Len(ctrl.Caption) - 8)
                        If left(ext, 1) = iRow And Right(ext, 1) = iCol Then
                            ctrl.Tag = rng.cells(iRow, iCol).Address
                            ctrl.Caption = rng.cells(iRow, iCol).Value
                            arrUsed(k) = ctrl.Caption: k = k + 1
                            ChkBColl.Add ctrl, ctrl.Name
                            Set ChkB(k).chkBEvent = ctrl
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next iCol
   Next iRow
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomething(chk As MSForms.CheckBox)
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   
   Set ws = Sheets("INDICATION-PRODUCT"): ws.Activate
   If chk.Value = True Then
        ws.Range(chk.Tag).Select 'do whatever needed with the cell...
   Else
        ws.Range("A1").Select
   End If
End Sub
```

Each check box `Tag` will receive the associated cell address.

In order to automatically allocate the same event to all of them, a simple class wrapper (named `ChkBoxChClss') will be created. It will identify the clicked check box and send the object to a form sub, where to be processed as needed. Please, paste the next code in the class:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents chkBEvent As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub chkBEvent_Change()
    frmChkBox.DoSomething chkBEvent
End Sub
```

You can use the `Public Sub DoSomething` to deal with the check box being clicked. Now, clicking a check box, **if its value is `True`** the correspondent cell will be selected. If `False`, the "A1" cell will be selected. You can do whatever you need.

Comment: This looks great! Thank you for the help, really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @soraia635: Glad I could help! But it may be interesting to programmatically create all necessary check boxes on the fly. In the same form `Initialize` event. They may receive the same common event, too. In this way there is no need of manually creating and naming a specific range of check boxes and their number does not matter, anymore. Of course, the code must be a little adapted...

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve it!

[image: This is a table I have on one my Worksheets.]

[image]

The table I have on my worksheet (Image 1) has the indication column that corresponds to the indication values on my userform. For each indication, there are several products.

I want my tool to be as flexible as possible, so I needed to match the indication name and for each checkbox in my userform I would obtain it's name from the table.

For example: Indication A, Prod 1 = Prod 1 (Checkbox.Name = Cell(x,y))

This is the code that I'm using:

```
Dim code_ind As String
Dim sel_ind As String
Dim chkbx As Control
Dim labx As Control
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim col_value As Integer
Dim row_value As Integer

For i = 1 To 8

Set chkbx = Me.Controls("seg_l_selInd_" & i)
sel_ind = tWb.Worksheets("INDICATION-PRODUCT").Columns(2).Find(what:=chkbx)

If chkbx = sel_ind Then
    col_value = 0
    While tWb.Worksheets("INDICATION-PRODUCT").Cells(i + 3, 3 + col_value) <> ""
    For j = 1 To 4
        
    Set labx = Me.Controls("seg_cb_selInd_" & i & j)
    labx.Caption = tWb.Worksheets("INDICATION-PRODUCT").Cells(i + 3, 3 + col_value)
    col_value = col_value + 1
    Next j
    Wend
End If
Next i
```

Does it make sense to you?
Is there any way to make my code more flexible? For example, I'm assuming there are 8 indications (i = 1 to 8), but realistically there could be more in the future.

Comment: When naming your product checkboxes you should have a separator between `i` and `j` or you may run into problems if you get >10 indications.

Comment: The most flexible approach would be to build the form content entirely from the worksheet table - that way you don't need to keep the form and the table in sync.  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530443/add-checkboxes-to-userform-based-on-cell-value

Comment: @TimWilliams so instead of having the checkboxes already in the userform they will be added depending on what's on the sheet. Is that right? That sounds like a better idea. Thank you!

Comment: Yes - it's a little more complicated but will be much more flexible and easier to maintain.