# Creating checkboxes in userform depending on parameters

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I want an user to select on which sheets he wants to create a new line of text. But the number of sheets he is able to select may vary over time and I don't want to hardcode the sheets' name.

Here is an example ("o" represents the checkbox) of what I aim to do:

```
o 01.2013
o 07.2013
o 01.2014
o 07.2014
```

I created an userform with an empty frame to put my checkboxes, and added this bit of code to the userform:

```
Private Tck(10) As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

i = 1

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(ws.Name, 3) = "T2M" Then
      Set Tck(i) = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i)
      Tck(i).Caption = Right(ws.Name, 7)
      i=i+1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

But it only adds one checkbox with the last sheet which validates the if test.

I tried to make an offset between the two iterations but I can't modify the position of the `Tck(i)` using `Tck(i).top` for example.

I also tried the method from the answer of this question : [Adding controls to a frame in an Excel userform with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563972/adding-controls-to-a-frame-in-an-excel-userform-with-vba) but it dosen't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your checkboxes are there, you just can't see them because they're overlayed on top of each other. You had the right idea with changing the 'Top' value.

```
Public Sub addCheckboxes()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tck As MSForms.CheckBox
    Dim offset As Integer: offset = 5

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Set ws = Worksheets(i)
        Set tck = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i, True)
        tck.Top = offset

        offset = offset + 15

    Next i
End Sub
```